# Need powerhsell command to check a file exist or not in file storage without error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

```
$Context = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "TestServices-RG" -Name "devstestsa").Context

$file=Get-AZStorageFile -ShareName "test-file-share" -Context $Context -Path "/test.json"
```

The above command works but it throws error if file does not exist. Is there any way to suppress this error.

**Error:**
The specified resource does not exist. HTTP Status Code: 404 - HTTP Error Message: The specified resource does not exist.
ErrorCode:
| ResourceNotFound
ErrorMessage: The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId: 50521f9b-701a-0034-6a8a-fba24a000000
Time: Fri, 05 Feb 2021
| 12:12:22 GMT

Get-AzStorageFile: untitled:Untitled-1:4:10
Line |
4 |     $file=Get-AZStorageFile -ShareName "test-file-share" -Context  …
|           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| The specified resource does not exist. HTTP Status Code: 404 - HTTP Error Message: The specified resource does not exist.
ErrorCode:
| ResourceNotFound
ErrorMessage: The specified resource does not exist.

Comment: you can put it in `try - catch` code block.

Comment: Does using the `-ErrorAction Ignore` common parameter on the Get-AzStorageFile command work for you?  [About CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the following PowerShell script

```
$account=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "" -Name ""

$share=Get-AzStorageShare -Name "share2" -Context $account.Context

$share.ShareClient.GetRootDirectoryClient().GetFileClient("test.json").Exists()
```

[image]
[image]